# Replaceable Navbar-items in MVC based on View-Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating an asp.net website with a layout page which contains a navigation bar(`Black area in the image`). Now I want to have specific elements in the navbar(`green`) based on the specific view content(`orange`)
  [image: sketch for the website(Navbar at top, with area for specific view elements, And below the view)]

So I want to set a Section in the layout page from the View. How can I do this? If thats not possible would it be possible to set the elements in the layout over variables in the viewbag? But I guess thats not a Best Practice

Best Regards and thanks for your help
Flo

Comment: would you like a solution with Jquery?

Comment: So unauthorized access is pushed to some default page of yours?

Comment: So you can have a default content in that case right? rather than updating it from the values ion viewbag

Comment: the default content would be none, so the navbar would contain no additional items, and I am sorry, basically a solution with JQuery would be okay, I will delete my other comments, as they are of no use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@section` keyword in Razor.

In your layout.cshtml:

```
<div id="@navbarId">
@* ... *@
    @if (IsSectionDefined("TopMenu")) {
        <div id="@topMenuId">
            @RenderSection("TopMenu")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Insert the menu content in your specific content view.cshtml:

```
@section TopMenu {
    <a href="...">Action</a>
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, thanks, it seems like I failed on doing proper research.